# Nautilus freeze after choosing any item from menu

Tags: 16.04, unity, nautilus

When I click on any element on the right top drop down menu something starts frequently blinking  and CPU load up to 100% until I clicked mouse button somewhere.
Console output:

```
$ nautilus
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
(nautilus:5730): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
(nautilus:5730): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
(nautilus:5730): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
(nautilus:5730): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
(nautilus:5730): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

How can I fix this behavior?
[image: screenshot]

Update:
This behavior identical for all applications with "old style" menu
[image]